# Why does the open A minor chord in 1st position sound better with the B string slightly flat?

Tags: tuning

I have been trying to understand why my A minor shape barre chords and specifically A minor in 1st position sounds better with the B string tuned slightly flat. In equal temperament the minor and major intervals are mostly affected by being around 15cents off. Is this perhaps what I am hearing? I thought about this a bit but then shouldn't it be the other way since the interval from A to C is a minor 3rd which means the B should be 15cents sharper not flatter to be closer to Just intonation yet it sound better with the B tune 15 cents flat. Can someone please help me make heads or tails of this please.

Comment: It may be as simple as the intonation on the guitar isn't as good as it should be.

Comment: @Tim I checked the fretted notes with a tuner.. it  was all good

Comment: I believe this video is talking EXACTLY about the phenomenon you're talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Daw93bRHe4Y

Comment: Do you mean "sound nicer to me" or "get rid of overtones caused by being out of tune" ?

Comment: Has to do with just versus equal temperament tuning.

Comment: @Richard the video talks about detuning the B string to make major intervals more in tune. Not minor. The interval from A to C is a minor 3rd

Comment: @b3ko this is what I was thinking but in equal temp tuning the minor 3rd is off by 15 cents in the other direction! IOW minor 3rds are 315cents in just temperament not 285 of that makes sense which means that the b would need to be sharpened

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the pure minor triad lies in the other direction (B-string tune 15 cents higher).

However, when you tune down the B-string by 33 cents, you arrive at another quite consonant chord, with A, C and E in a frequency ratio of 6:7:9. You know you're there, when the chord is completed by playing the open D string, which would be the two octaves above the fundamental note here. I'd also say the 7:8:9-chord is more consonant than the minor triad, but keep in mind, it's a different chord and it will not fit the same context as a minor triad.